# Get-ADUser returning an irregular table

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am running `Get-ADuser` as a part of a much larger script involving multiple run-spaces. For some reason, the last run-space to process returns a strange output for `Get-ADuser`.

Normal (expected) Output:

[image: Normal output for get-aduser with properties]

Odd Output:

[image: it does not show the properties]

```
$UserState = Get-ADUser $username -Credential $credentials -Properties AccountExpirationDate,LockedOut
Write-Warning ($UserState | Format-List | Out-String)
```

Comment: seem to be a serialization issue. need more code to understand what it could be. you can most likely solve it by using `Select-Object` before outputting from the runspaces

Comment: Are you aware that you do not have to parse "string output" of cmdlets in PowerShell? It is just *one* representation of the actual .NET objects.